# No result when trying to download webpage using Jsoup 1.8.1

Tags: jsoup

in my project I am trying to use Jsoup1.8.1 to download a webpage but I can not do this.
when I open that webpage("http://checkip.dyndns.org/") in my browser and parse source of it. there is results. but when i want to use this code i can not see results.

This is my code.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://checkip.dyndns.org").
String title = doc.html().toString();
TextView tv0=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv0.setText(title)
```

Comment: after one hour still no comment and no answer.

Comment: @gudthing, `TextView` is part of Android's UI toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.get()` at the end of your first line of code. You need to call this method to get Jsoup to download the document, which will otherwise be blank.
Do it like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://checkip.dyndns.org").get();
String title = doc.title(); //You prob. want only the title, and not the whole HTML..
TextView tv0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
tv0.setText(title);
```

Comment: sorry. i lose inserting .get() method in here. but in eclipse i inserted it.

Comment: @davidlog, Did you try setting the user agent to something a normal web browser would use ?

Comment: no. the problem were solved. i must put a code to check when connecting to server. and seeing no result may be is from this. when i click several times button that executes this codes. i see some results. may be problem is from my internet service provider. or internet speed. thank you and others.

Answer (score 0):

Dyndns purposely prevents parsers from downloading the webpage (DynDns service is to be used only when you are using [their services](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/checkip-tool/)). Just use a different one like: http://ipecho.net/plain.

I am unfamiliar with Android, but this works fine for me:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://ipecho.net/plain").get();
String title = doc1.html().toString();
System.out.println(title);
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        1xx.xx.xxx.xxx
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set user agent to one of a normal browser, the website should not be able to know that you are using a parser, and it should work, right ?

Comment: @davidlog `but when i want to use this code i can not see results.`. Yes, DynDns will work in browser, but the code above will not work with it. Did you try using ipecho?

Comment: i tested it in browser and it works. ipecho has no other text than ip address.

Comment: @davidlog as I mentioned earlier, jsoup code you provided will not work with dyndns. Dyndns will only work directly through a browser, not a parser.

Comment: browser is a program that uses parser inside it.and logically must not be any difference with code that we write.